# How to calculate a wake vector for a vessel moving through water?

Tags: energy, fluid-dynamics, waves, kinematics

We are trying to calculate a vector that will point at the river bank where the vessels wake will hit based on its speed. The bank is not consistent and it is always changing. Since the bank is always changing and we don't know its exact location, we cannot calculate the exact location the wake will hit the bank. We are trying to, however, draw a visual true vector on the chart that will show the direction the wake is headed. We would like the vector to start at the bow/tip of the vessel. Imagine someone standing on the bow pointing their finger at what direction the wake will head. We would like to draw a vector in that direction. If we can draw that vector line at let's say 1 mile, it would intersect with the bank at some point. This intersection point would hopefully be where the wake would hit the bank.

See the following image:
[image: vessel]

In this picture, we have drawn the wake angle off the bow of the ship using the [Kelvin Wake Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake#Kelvin_wake_pattern) constant of 19.47 degrees (the triangle / cone coming off the bow). This allows us to see what the wake would look like from above, but it does not help us figure out at what path will the wake a specified instant follow. Would a linear vector like this even exist or would it be curved? Would the speed make a difference in where the wake would hit the bank?

Comment: Your question is based on the false premise that a wave is generates at one point and travels along a known path (a straight line) to one other point. In reality (think about the Huygens construction) at every point a wave front is made up of the interference of all points on the wave front from a moment ago. Please consider whether your question makes sense in the light of this. The locus of the wave front might make more sense as a thing to compute - but "the wave I create right now" doesn't hit just one point on the bank.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. Perhaps the following answers your question:

When looked at from the reference frame of the vessel, you already know the direction in which the wake line lies, so you already have a constant unit vector $\mathbf{w}$ pointing in that direction. If the bank is moving (again as seen from the reference frame of the vessel) then you need to specify position vectors to any two points with the vessel as the origin, call it $\mathbf{p}_1,\mathbf{p}_2$ (for convenience you may pick those points to be fixed on the bank when looked at from the reference frame of the bank). As seen from the vessel both $\mathbf{p}_1,\mathbf{p}_2,$ are functions of time $t$. The vector to any point on the bank, as seen from the reference frame of the vessel, is given by $\mathbf{p}(a,t)=\mathbf{p}_1(t)+a(\mathbf{p}_2(t)-\mathbf{p}_1(t))$, where $a$ is a real number; $a$ is the parameter for the bank line at a given time $t$ (i.e. different values of $a$ give you different points on the bank at any given time instant). You want the position vector of the point on the bank which is colinear with $\mathbf{w}$, i.e. if at some time instant $t$, $\mathbf{p}(a,t)$ is the position vector of the point on the bank where wake intersects it, then we need $\mathbf{p}(a,t)\times \mathbf{w}=\mathbf{0}$, which allows you to find $a$. From this you may calculate distance to the point where the wake hits the bank from any specified reference point.

Comment: I guess the problem is we don't know the time. And I guess we cannot assume the wake would be linear based on time. It might not even be possible.